# Load Microsoft Document in Flash Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I want to load microsoft word/excel document into swf. I have written the actionscript like following:-

---

```
var myloader:Loader = new Loader();

myloader.load(new URLRequest("test.doc"));

board.addChild(myloader);
```

Thanks in advance,

### Prosenjit

But this code is not working. May I need to have a parser.

Can someone please help me out for this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible like that. You have to convert your document file to swf first.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but is there any parser to read word/excel document in actionscript3?

Comment: [There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879405/how-to-read-excel2007-xlsx-sheet-using-actionscriptair) was a question about Excel. But we are converting documents to sfw files with [Print2Flash](http://print2flash.com/).

Answer (score 0):

My github project may be able to help you out https://github.com/childoftv/as3-xlsx-reader